# Azure WebJob: BlobTrigger vs QueueTrigger resource usage

Tags: azure

I created a WebJob project to backup images from Azure to Amazon that used the BlobTrigger attribute for the first parameter in the method

```
    public static async Task CopyImage([BlobTrigger("images/{name}")] ICloudBlob image, string name, TextWriter log)
    {
        var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.DownloadToStream(imageStream);
        await S3ImageBackupContext.UploadImageAsync(name, imageStream);
    }
```

Then I read that the BlobTrigger is based on the *best effort basis* in the document [How to use Azure blob storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/)  and changed it to a QueueTrigger.

Both works perfectly fine :-) so it's not a problem but a question. Since I deployed the change the CPU and Memory usage of the WebJob looks like

[image: CPU Memory usage]

Can somebody explain me the reason for the drop of memory and CPU usage? Also the data egress went down.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting.

I think you're the only one who can answer that question.

Do a remote profile for both blob and queue versions, see which method eats up that CPU time:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/

For memory consumption you probably need to grab a memory dump:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/07/01/create-a-memory-dump-for-your-slow-performing-web-app/